# Creating a tastypie resource with a foreign key without exposing the foreign key as a resource

Tags: django, tastypie

There were a number of questions that looked similar to mine but none of them seemed to cover my particular formulation. Apologies if I missed one that covers this.

I have a tastypie ModelResource that is representing a model with a ForeignKey. I want to be able to create new resources of that type, but I don't want to expose the model of the foreign key to the api.

It would be fine to add a resource for it, but I don't want anything external to the site code to be able to read/write the foreign key. From what I've attempted so far though, tastypie seems to only be able to handle this type of foreign key if the corresponding foreign key model also has a resource that can be created. I just want to be able to create models that reference existing foreign key objects, not allow the creation of new ones.

Is this something that can be done in tastypie? If so, what do I need to do in order to accomplish this? If not, is there some kind of work-around/compromise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want a foreign key to be visible on api, just don't make a field for it in the resource.
If you need to specify some value to it on create/update you can overwrite obj_create/obj_update tastypie methods for this resource. For example:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    obj = super(YourResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, **kwargs)
    obj.yourforeighnkey = somevalue
    obj.save()
    return obj
```

Comment: I did a bit more looking and found a solution that may be similar to what you're suggesting, but I don't want to submit it as the answer if it isn't the correct method of doing this. On my resource instead of adding the foreign key as a foreign key, I just added it as an integer field with the same name as the foreign key field in the represented model. Would that be an acceptable method of doing it or should I be overriding the obj_create?

Comment: It depends on what you want. If you add it as a integer field it will be visible via api as integer field and if you dont set it set readonly it can be changed via api..

Comment: For my purposes its fine if the primary key of the foreign key is visible, what I wanted to prevent was having to add the entire foreign key object to the api with the same permissions as the models that reference it. I didn't think about the read-only part though, so that's definitely helpful. If I mark it as read-only, will that prevent creating new resources through the api or is there an exception for creating resources?